# PHP include paths within directories

Tags: php, include-path

I have looked around at a few different questions about the same sort of problem I'm having. I have took a solution and adapted it to my own project.

Here is my directory structure.

```
/css
    -style.css
/includes
    -shop.css
    -header.php
    -footer.php
/php
/js
/shop
    -index.php

-index.php <-- homepage
-config.php
```

Inside my config.php I have

```
define('ROOT_PATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

My header.php

```
<?php include './config.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <?php echo '<link href="'.ROOT_PATH.'/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">';?>
  <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/shop/'){echo '<link href="'.ROOT_PATH.'/includes/shop.css" rel="stylesheet">';} ?>
</head>
```

The only problem is, for any other page other than the root index.php file, the path for the config.php file becomes incorrect. Thus the CSS paths then become incorrect as `ROOT_PATH` isn't defined anywhere.

What would be the best way to handle paths when using includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gets the document root for eg `var/com/images`. `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will get current url like `http://example.com/images`.TYour code should look like this

```
define('ROOT_PATH',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

And include this way

```
<?php include'../config.php';
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using relative paths for the include in the other index.php file.

```
<?php include '../config.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the server's actual filesystem path to refer to your stylesheets. That's like trying to do something like:

```
<link href="C:\your_website_path/includes/shop.css"...
```

and wont work.

I would recommend to change that to something like:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', 'http://www.your-website-url.com/');
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is make the include for your config absolute, not relative.  you begin the path with a dot `./config` which means its relative.  instead set up your header to include the config file with an absolute path like this

```
<?php include '/home/user/config.php';?>
```

This way, any page can find the file no matter its location in the directory structure.